# Woody shrub with small beige flowers from south-central Europe

Tags: identification, shrubs

This woody shrub from a yard was collected in South-Central Europe. It has slightly lobed ovate leaves, and several clusters of beige flowers on slender stems.

[image]

Comment: I am curious @Quantomic ;  what is this 12 part series?  This is a very interesting/exciting/fun idea...

Comment: It's really nothing of the sorts, although something like that really does sound nice. I have 12 plants I needed to identify so I made one big question, but I was told to split it up, so now I'm doing this. Although, I'll probably end the series here since I probably won't need the other plants and some I identified myself.

Comment: Brilliant!  You should be stirring up some activity here!  Ask away.  ID is like playing a game.  Be far nicer to actually see, touch, feel, smell but we do a pretty good job and this is very good practice.

Comment: I may as well post the plants I don't need answers to just for the fun part. Stay tuned for more, probably will upload the next one tomorrow. Until then you can try the first question out. The link is in the question

Comment: There you go!  Great plan...especially if you already know what they are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my guess is [Ninebark; Physocarpus opulifolius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physocarpus_opulifolius). Here's a picture of one: [Ninebark opulifolius](http://www.miseagrant.umich.edu/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/03/Ninebark-Physocarpus_opulifolius-01.jpg)